# When I run my code it shows 500 error with POST and GET methods

Tags: c#, angularjs, mvvm, typescript

I'm new to `mvvm` can anybody help me to display details based on the date selected. When I run my code it shows `500` error with `post` and `get` methods.

**Schedule.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-lg-8" ng-app="ScheduleApp" ng-controller="ScheduleController" ng-cloak>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Select Date</td>
                            <td>
                                                               <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dt" name="dt">
                                <input type="button" ng-click="vm.GetDetails(dt)" value="check" class="btn btn-default"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Trip ID</b></td>
                            <td><b>Booked By</b></td>
                            <td><b>Phone</b></td>
                            <td><b>Email</b></td>
                            <td><b>Car</b></td>
                            <td><b>Driver</b></td>
                            <td><b>Time</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="c in vm.books">
                            <td><p id="p1">{{c.TripId}}</p></td>
                            <td><p id="p2">{{c.BookedBy}}</p></td>
                            <td><p id="p3">{{c.Phone}}</p></td>
                            <td><p id="p4">{{c.Email}}</p></td>
                            <td><p id="p5">{{c.CarId}}</p></td>
                            <td><p id="p6">{{c.DriverId}}</p></td>
                            <td><p id="p7">{{c.StartTime}}</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

**ScheduleController.cs**

```
    public JsonResult GetData(DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {

            babyEntities1 ctx = new babyEntities1();
            var bookings = from c in ctx.Trips
                        where c.Date == dt
                           select new
                           {
                               c.TripId,
                               c.BookingNo,
                               c.Date,
                               c.StartTime,
                               c.EndTime,
                               c.AccountId,
                               c.BookedBy,
                               c.PaxId,
                               c.PaxNo,
                               c.Phone,
                               c.SourceId,
                               c.SourceAddressId,
                               c.DestinationID,
                               c.DestAddressId,
                               c.Via,
                               c.Flight,
                               c.PaxComments,
                               c.TripEnd,
                               c.CarId,
                               c.DriverId,
                               c.PayId,
                               c.Amount,
                               c.Toll,
                               c.Parking,
                               c.FuelSur,
                               c.CardId,
                               c.AdminFee,
                               c.ExtraFee,
                               c.FeeComments,
                               c.UserId,
                               c.TotalAmount
                           };

            return Json(bookings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { msg = "error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**ScheduleController.ts**

```
module Main.Schedule {

    export interface IScheduleScope extends ng.IScope {
        vm: ScheduleController;

    }

    export class ScheduleController {
        public isBusy: boolean;
        public books: Main.Book.Book;
        //Default constructor
        constructor(private $scope: IScheduleScope, private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            $scope.vm = this;
           // this.books = new Main.Book.Book();
           // var dt: Date;
          //  this.GetData(dt);
        }
        public GetDetails(dt: Date): void {
            this.$http.post("/Schedule/GetData", { Obj: this.GetData }).success((data: any, status: any) => {
                if (data.msg == 'success') {
                    this.GetData(dt);
                    alert("Saved");
                }
                else
                    alert('Error');
            }).error((data: any, status: any) => {
                    alert("Error");
                });
        }

        public GetData(dt: Date): void {
                this.$http.get("/Schedule/GetData").success((data: any, status: any) => {
                this.books = data;
                this.isBusy = false;
                console.log(data);
            }).error((data: any, status: any) => {
                    alert("Error");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the error? Do you know if the error is server side or client side? Have you debugged it using Dev Tools in the browser of your choice? Have you seen the raw HTTP requests and responses? Posting all of your code and asking us to find your issue is not likely to get the response you are hoping for.

Comment: @Bill its post 500 internal server error

Comment: That means that your server threw an unhandled exception. You need to get more verbose error logging from your server, or ideally debug the server and step through to see where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

you don't pass the dateTime to the request.

```
public GetData(dt: Date): void {
                this.$http.get("/Schedule/GetData").suc
```

I guess that's why your controller returns a 500. 
consider instead

```
public GetData(dt: Date): void {
                    this.$http.get("/Schedule/GetData?dt=" + dt.toString()).suc
```

But I'm pretty sure you have to format your datetime in a way both c# and javascript will understand

Answer (score 0):

thnxx to all. I sorted it out nd d updated code is...

```
 public GetDetails(dt: string): void {
        this.$http.get("/Schedule/GetData", { params: { dt: dt } }).success((data: any, status: any) => {
            this.tripview = data;
            console.log(data);
        }).error((data: any, status: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            });
    }

    public GetData(dt: string): void {
        this.$http.get("/Schedule/GetData", { params: {} }).success((data: any, status: any) => {
            this.tripview = data;
            this.isBusy = false;
            console.log(data);
        }).error((data: any, status: any) => {
                alert("Error");
        });
    }
```